# Gogle Cloud Data Fusion Post GresQL read from follower database

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

So, like the title I am trying to read from a PostGres follower database using Google Cloud Data Fusion so I can pipeline to big query. I keep running into the issue.

```
01/04/2022 0:28:52
INFO
Pipeline '2bf2d105-6d1f-11ec-9f9d-7ee8fe64661a' is started by user 'root' with arguments {isolationLevel=READ_COMMITTED, logical.start.time=1641274129122, system.profile.name=SYSTEM:dataproc, default_transaction_isolation=repeatable read, isolationlevel=READ_COMMITTED}
01/04/2022 0:28:52
INFO
Pipeline '2bf2d105-6d1f-11ec-9f9d-7ee8fe64661a' running
01/04/2022 0:29:15
ERROR
Spark program 'phase-1' failed with error: ERROR: cannot use serializable mode in a hot standby Detail: "default_transaction_isolation" is set to "serializable". Hint: You can use "SET default_transaction_isolation = 'repeatable read'" to change the default.. Please check the system logs for more details.
01/04/2022 0:29:15
ERROR
Pipeline '2bf2d105-6d1f-11ec-9f9d-7ee8fe64661a' failed.
```

I understand what it is telling me and why, but I can't for the life of me get Cloud Data Fusion to run postgresql-9.4.1211.jar with the argument for transaction isolation, which seems to be --isolationLevel=READ_COMMITTED according to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Can someone help me understand what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Which PostGres follower database are you using? How are you trying to connect a PostGres follower database to data fusion?

Comment: It's not my DB, but the vendor says it's PostGres 13. I am connecting to it with JDBC postgresql-9.4.1211.jar. Though I can't seem to understand how to give it proper arguments so that the transaction isolation is changed per query. Adding it to the query itself, causes a spark error about 0 results being returned since the set command issues results before the select from the table.

Comment: Can you try to change the transaction isolation level on the advanced options by setting it to “TRANSACTION_REPETABLE_READ” by going to
Cloud Data Fusion > Pipeline> Database > Database Properties > Advanced > Transaction Isolation Level. Let me know if the pipeline executes successfully after this modification.

Comment: Hi @Slacker101, Does the above comment resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I could solve it as stated by "Prajna Rai T" but using "Database pluging" instead of "BigQuery plugin", which doesn't have the "Transaction Isolation Level" property.